# Feed Slim Training Loop with Data Batches from Keras ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have an ImageDataGenerator object from Keras which yields batches indefinitely. How can I feed n batches of size s each to training loop of tensorflow-slim.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=20,
  width_shift_range=0.2,
  height_shift_range=0.2,
  horizontal_flip=True)
for X_batch, Y_batch in datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=s):
    # here I want to feed X_batch and Y_batch to slim.learning.train to run train_op in a loop

    batches += 1
    if batches >= n:
        # we need to break the loop by hand because
        # the generator loops indefinitely
        break
```

Please note that I want to use training loop provided by tensor-slim rather than writing my own routine for training using native tensorflow.